# Why does Entity Framework throw attaching entity errors when setting status to Modified?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Perplexed by an occurrence of the common Entity Framework error

> "Attaching an entity of type 'MyType' failed because
>   another entity of the same type already has the same primary key
>   value.

My understanding of this error is that it meant there was another object somewhere in the graph of that object type which had a duplicate primary key, preventing a second copy being attached.

But that understanding must be wrong, because the error is occurring here:

```
public void Update(MyType updateItem)
{
    if (updateItem != null)
    {
        // debug code, which tells me there is only one match
        var foo = Entities.MyTypes.Where(x => x.MyTypeId == updateItem.MyTypeId);

        if (Entities.MyTypes.Any(itm => itm.MyTypeId == updateItem.MyTypeId))
        {
            // error here
            Entities.Entry(updateItem).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {
            Entities.MyTypes.Add(updateItem);
        }
    }
}
```

So that's not trying to add, or re-attach a new object, it's just saying that an existing object is marked as modified, right?

Can someone please explain to me the process here, so I can try and understand and fix the problem?

EDIT: This is the SQL it's trying to run

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[MyType] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[MyTypeId] = @p__linq__0
)) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=4749
```

Which returns a C1 value of 1. The next entry in the trace is the logger logging the error.

Comment: What's the primary key of `updateItem`? Are you using sql server?

Comment: @KosalaW It's SQL Server. The primary key is a standard, auto-incrementing int indentity (1,1) Id field.

Comment: The error is coming from your database. By looking at the above code, we can't say what's happening. To diagnose this issue, you have to use `sql server profiler`. Start the profiler, run your system and capture the sql that throws this primary key violation exception. Then you should be able to figure out why it's trying to insert/update identity value.

Comment: If you are using edmx, make sure your model is updated with latest database changes.

Comment: I had the same problem, but if You would look at this article Craig comment you can solve it, but in other way...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894587/how-to-update-record-using-entity-framework-6

Comment: @KosalaW OK, I've got a planning meeting now but will check the profile when I get out. I was under the impression that EF normally gave you actual Db level errors in the InnerException, but there's nothing like that here.

Comment: That's a valid point. It's hard to diagnose db level issues by looking at EF exceptions. As DntQuitPls mentioned, it's better to change your syntax to less confusing _load and update_ syntax. Also Change your method name to `AddUpdate` if you are planing to perform both add and update in the same function.

Comment: @KosalaW As I suspected, there's no SQL error. I've updated the question with the sql that it's running, which seems to be fine.

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on [ASP.NET MVC - Attaching an entity of type 'MODELNAME' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent/39557606#39557606).

Answer (score 0):

After many wasted hours, I discovered that this works, as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31771363/271907

```
// needs this namespace
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

public void Update(MyType updateItem)
{
    if (updateItem != null)
    {
        if (Entities.MyTypes.Any(itm => itm.MyTypeId == updateItem.MyTypeId))
        {
            try
            {
                Entities.Entry(updateItem).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            }
            catch
            {
                Entities.Set<MyType>().AddOrUpdate(updateItem);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Entities.MyTypes.Add(updateItem);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I must confess I do not understand *why* it works at all and I remain bemused by the cause of the original error.

I likely don't need the try/catch block in there - perhaps I should just swap out the `State = Modified` for the call to `AddOrUpdate()`. But because the old code was functional, and I'm not sure why this works, I felt it wisest to leave it alone.