# How can I update database records?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have code like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public static bool AggiornaInstallatore(FormCollection form)
{
    using (var ctx = new termostore_installazione_Entities())
    {
        var idr = Convert.ToInt32(form["id_installatore"]);
        var installatore = ctx.installatori.Where(x => x.Id == idr).FirstOrDefault();
        var squad = Convert.ToInt16(form["squadra"]);
        var squadra = ctx.squadra.Where(x => x.id == squad).FirstOrDefault();

        if (form["edit_nome"] != "") { installatore.nome = form["edit_nome"]; }
        if (form["edit_cognome"] != "") { installatore.cognome = form["edit_cognome"]; }
        if (form["edit_email"] != "") { installatore.mail = form["edit_email"]; }
        if (form["edit_telefono"] != "") { installatore.telefono = form["edit_telefono"]; }
        if (form["edit_indirizzo"] != "") { installatore.indirizzo = form["edit_indirizzo"]; }
        if (form["edit_zona_competenza"] != "") { installatore.zona_competenza = form["edit_zona_competenza"]; }

        installatore.squadra.Add(squadra);

        ctx.SaveChanges();

    }
    return true;
}
```

Now, instead of adding `squadra` I want to update this record, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Just do the changes that you want to do in "squadra". The changes will be persisted through ctx.SaveChanges().

Comment: Simply call `SaveChanges`. Entities are tracked in your context, when changes are made then the item will be marked as state `Modified`

Comment: Don't do database operations directly in your controller! Follow some separation of concerns. Have a separate database layer responsible for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update record using Entity Framework 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894587/how-to-update-record-using-entity-framework-6)

Comment: The junction table record represents a simple link, what really do you want to "update" of that record?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of add the element `squadra` to the list, you can update every single element of the object from the db like that:

```
//The element you already have in your example
var squadra = ctx.squadra.Where(x => x.id == squad).FirstOrDefault();

squadra.name = form.name; //I assume you get te updated value from form
squadra.type = form.type;
...

ctx.SaveChanges();
```

You have the squad element updated and, with the `SaveChanges` method, the updates are set even on the db.

Comment: But the situation is more complex... *installatore.squadra* is a junction table between two tables which have many to many relationship. Then, I will reply my question: how can I update the record?

Comment: Is it a view then?

Comment: There are three tables: first table *installatori*, second table *squadra* and third junction table *appartiene_squadra* which is beetween the first two tables. I want update record of the junction table.