# Updating entry adds a new entry to database

Tags: c#, linq

I am making a POST call to Add a flower to the database, but I want to update a record in another table if the if statement is true. If the statement is not true, it adds the flower without any problems but when I am trying to update `PinkRoseId` with a new id, it creates a new record instead of updating the old one.

Is there another way to update the database?

```
public void AddFlower(Flower flowerToAdd, int someId)
{
    _flowerContext = _contextUtility.GetFlowerContext(flowerToAdd.FlowerName);
    var pinkRoseId = _flowerService.GetFlowerIdByName(flowerToAdd.FlowerName, "PinkRose", "Rose");

    if (flowerToAdd.SomeFlowerId.HasValue)
    {
        var flowerToUpdate = _updateService.UpdateFlowerBySomething(flowerToAdd.FlowerName, flowerToAdd.SomeFlowerId.Value, flowerToAdd.PetalAk);
        flowerToUpdate.PinkRoseId = pinkRoseId;
        _flowerContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    var firstId  = _petalService.GetFlowerIdByName(flowerToAdd.FlowerName, "rose", "petal");
    var secondId = _sunService.GetSunIdByTypeOf(flowerToAdd.FlowerName, flowerToAdd.SomeName, "sun");

    flowerToAdd.FlowerId        = secondId;
    flowerToAdd.SomeOtherId     = firstId;
    flowerToAdd.CreatedDate     = DateTime.UtcNow;
    flowerToAdd.CreatedByUserID = someId;

    _flowerContext.Flowers.Add(flowerToAdd);
    _flowerContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On reading more about Entity Framework, there is  method `AddOrUpdate` which adds a new record or updates any existing records. Side note: I am using EF6 (not sure if AddOrUpdate is available in any older versions or not)

## Solution 1

```
if (flowerToAdd.SomeFlowerId.HasValue)
{
    var flowerToUpdate = _updateService.UpdateFlowerBySomething(flowerToAdd.FlowerName, flowerToAdd.SomeFlowerId.Value, flowerToAdd.PetalAk);
}
```

`_flowerContext.Flower.AddOrUpdate(flowerToUpdate);` -- this did the trick and updated the existing record instead of adding a new one

Using this method is highly discouraged as per my understanding as it can add new records. Yet to find another solution.

## Solution 2

I figured out another way to get this done without using `AddOrUpdate`

```
var changeRequest = (from x in _flowerContext.FlowerUpdateSomething
                     where x.FlowerPrimaryId == flowerToUpdate.FlowerPrimaryId
                     select x).FirstOrDefault();

changeRequest.PinkRoseId = pinkRoseId;
_flowerContext.SaveChanges();
```

}

#### Update on Solution 2:

I copied the solution to another service (eg SunFlowerService) like the following:

```
public SomeDataBaseEntity UpdateFlower(int id) 
{
    var changeRequest = (from x in _flowerContext.FlowerUpdateSomething
                         where x.FlowerPrimaryId == id
                         select x).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But now when I call this method like the following:

```
if (flowerToAdd.SomeFlowerId.HasValue)
{
    var flowerToUpdate = _updateService.UpdateFlowerBySomething(flowerToAdd.FlowerName, flowerToAdd.SomeFlowerId.Value, flowerToAdd.PetalAk);
    var update = _someOtherService.UpdateFlower(flowerToUpdate.Id);

    update.PinkFlowerId = pinkFlowerId;
    _flowerContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

It does not update the record in the database. I am not sure how to solve this problem, or why it would have such behavior. But on keeping the original LINQ query like the following:

```
var changeRequest = (from x in _flowerContext.FlowerUpdateSomething
                     where x.FlowerPrimaryId == flowerToUpdate.FlowerPrimaryId
                     select x).FirstOrDefault();

 changeRequest.PinkRoseId = pinkRoseId;
_flowerContext.SaveChanges();
```

I am able to change the records in the database. Not sure why making another method doesn't work.