# Entityframework how to update all children property when updating the parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have simple repository method in my asp.net core webapi. I am using EF core 2.0. When i update the parent startdate property, i would like to update all the related children to have the same start date. How to achieve this? There is One to Many relation with Course and CourseFormat.

Here is my code snippet:

```
public Course SaveCourse(Course item)            
{
    if (item.CourseId == 0)
        _context.Course.Add(item);
    else
    {
        var existing = _context.Course.SingleOrDefault(course => course.CourseId == item.CourseId);
        existing.CourseCode = item.CourseCode;
        existing.CourseName = item.CourseName;
        existing.Purpose = item.Purpose;
        existing.CourseDescription = item.CourseDescription;
        existing.AutomaticNotifications = item.AutomaticNotifications;
        existing.StartDate = item.StartDate;
        existing.EndDate = item.EndDate;
        existing.ModifiedBy = item.ModifiedBy;
        existing.Modified = item.Modified;
**// trying the following. is this right?**
        foreach(var courseFormat in existing.CourseFormat)
            courseFormat.StartYear = existing.StartDate.Value.Year;
        item.CreatedBy = existing.CreatedBy;
        item.Created = existing.Created;
    }

    _context.SaveChanges();
    return item;
}
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894587/how-to-update-record-using-entity-framework-6

Comment: https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Migrations/DbSetMigrationsExtensions.cs#L79

Comment: Good comment by xdtTransform! I would also like to see how the Course and CourseFormat objects look

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It's not clear if your code does what you  expect it to do.

Comment: Just make sure `existing.CourseFormat` collection is *loaded* using one of the [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) methods. Other than that, it's no different than updating the "parent" entity.

Comment: Yeah, but you never tell if it actually works, making it unclear what your'e asking.