# Unable to update Entity Framework entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I got this `PATCH` endpoint in my C# ASP.NET Core Web API that uses Entity Framework to store my games:

```
[HttpPatch]
public async Task<ActionResult<Game>> GetGame(long id) {

  var game = await _context.Games.FindAsync(id);

  if (game == null) {
    return NotFound();
  }

  game.State.Map = MapUtils.generateMap();

  _context.Entry(game).State = EntityState.Modified;

  try {
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  }
  catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) {
    if (!GameUtils.GameExists(_context, id)) {
      return NotFound();
    }
    else {
      throw;
    }
  }

  return game;
}
```

When this function is called I get the updated game with `Map` being set to a `List` of rows and columns as the response. But then when I use my `GET` endpoint to retrieve the updated game at a later stage, `map` is `null` which means that my entry couldn't have been updated when calling the `PATCH`.

Here is the `GET` for retrieving a single game:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Game>> GetGame(long id) {
  var game = await _context.Games.FindAsync(id);

  if (game == null) {
    return NotFound();
  }

  return game;
}
```

I've tried some solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894587/how-to-update-record-using-entity-framework-6) but I get the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have just assigned the value, but where is the .update() getting called over the entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
_context.Entry(game).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

will mark only the `game` entity as modified, not it's related entities.

Use -

```cs
_context.Games.Update(game);
```

instead to include the related entities.

Also, take a look at [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.update?view=efcore-3.1) to understand what this method tries to do behind the scene. Specifically, this part -

> "For entity types with generated keys if an entity has its primary key
> value set then it will be tracked in the Modified state. If the
> primary key value is not set then it will be tracked in the Added
> state."

In short, if the related entities don't have primary keys set, EF will try to Add the instead of Updating.

Finally, both in your GET and PATCH method include `Map` in the query -

```cs
var game = await _context.Games.Include(p => p.State).ThenInclude(p => p.Map).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
```

Take a look at [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Comment: Still getting the same result :|

Comment: Seemed promising but `Map` is still null in the response... I get the `State` regardless of if I use the second part of your answer with the `.Include`.

Comment: Could you please share your model classes? And did you update the query in your `PATCH` method too?

Comment: Ok now that I added it to PATCH as well I get the `Map`.. but its `Rows` and `Columns` is still not there. `Rows` and `Columns` in the `Map` are `List`s, so how to include all of those as well?  Is there not a method which includes all entries so you don't have to do this in every endpoint?

Comment: Used more .ThenInclude for Rows and Columns, but jesus this will bloat my codebase. I should probably move this to some sort of utils class no?

Comment: Doing database queries in your controller action methods is not the best practice anyway. You should have a Service/Repository layer for that purpose.