# Rework Delete Function to Change Databse Value ASP.Net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using ASP.Net and used EntityFramework to create my controller. In the controller there is the usual Delete and DeleteConfirmed actions. I don't ever want a user to actually delete a record but wouldn't mind that they think they deleted a record. My goal is to rework the delete confirmed record to change my RecordEntry table, IsValid column to 0 or false, meaning the record is marked as invalid rather than it being deleted.

This is the code for DeleteConfirmed. It has not yet been edited.

```
        // POST: RecordEntry/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var recordEntry = await _context.RecordEntry.FindAsync(id);
            _context.RecordEntry.Remove(recordEntry);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

Comment: And what's the problem? What stops you from just editing the code?

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla I don't know how. I know I need to do _context.RecordEntry.Update instead of .Remove but I don't know what else

Comment: Read the record out of the db by its id, update the property you want to update, save it back. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select entry and then change it's values, you can already simply save changes to database.

```
// POST: RecordEntry/Delete/5 
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")] 
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] 
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id) { 
    var recordEntry = await _context.RecordEntry.FindAsync(id); // get entry
    recordEntry.IsValid = false; // Edit entry
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); // Save changes to db
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index)); // Return response
}
```

If you want to know more, please refer here ([How to update record using Entity Framework 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894587/how-to-update-record-using-entity-framework-6))

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I've been happy to help!